# Which version of ngx-Toastr supports version 13.0.4 of Angular CLI? How to install ngx-Toastr this version?How to install ngx-Toastr certain version?

Tags: angular, toastr, ngx-toastr

I have an Angular project. My global Angular CLI version is 14.2.1, and my local Angular CLI version is 13.0.4.
Newest version of ngx-Toastr supports Angular CLI version 14.0.0 and and more, so it doesn't support Angular CLI 13.0.4 and it won't work with it. So I supposed, that early versions of ngx-Toastr can support Angular CLI 13.0.4, but I dunno what version really does.
Also I dunno how to install ngx-Toastr certain version. I know how to install ngx-Toastr newest version:

> npm install ngx-toastr --save

and also @angular/animations package:

> npm install @angular/animations --save

But this line "npm install ngx-toastr --save" - how to set what version I want to install?

P. S.: I'm looking for the way where I won't need to upgrade my local Angular CLI version - Angular CLI version of my project.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the list of old versions.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-toastr?activeTab=versions

click on version number and you will be navigated to that version. [image]

Or you can directly install any npm package as `npm i packageName@packageVersion`.

- Note: You have to figure out which version works with `13.0.4` of Angular.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry, do you happen to know which version of the ngx-Toastr works with Angular CLI 13.0.4?

Comment: No mate i have no idea, but angular 13 released on November 3, 2021 so try versions prior to that date or month.